# What is the opposite of jQuery's .is() selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to make an hover function with the `is()` selector. But what I need is the opposite!

```
$('.tray .tab').is(".active").hover(
...function
);
```

I tried the `not()` selector but this a filtering method, so it doesn't work the way I want it to.

```
$('.tray .tab').not(".active").hover(
...function
);
```

What I'm trying to do is if you hover an element containing the class `active`, the function shouldn't be executed.

```
<div class='tray'>
    <div class='tab'>Tab 1</div>
    <div class='tab active'>Tab 1</div>
    <div class='tab'>Tab 3</div>
</div>
```

I know this can be achieved by checking it with `if( $(this).is('.active') ){}`, but isn't there a straight way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

[EDIT:]

I guess it is the `not()` method I need! But when an element starts out with the class `active` it works, but when I add it with `addClass()` it doesn't. How come?

Comment: `is()` returns true of false not a jquery object.

Comment: You're right! Can't believe I overlooked that mistake. So it is `not()` I need.. But it won't do what I want..

Comment: You can either use event delegation or just check in the function if the class is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is` returns a boolean value and is not a chainable method as it doesn't return a jQuery object, use event delegation.

```
$('.tray').on({
   mouseenter: function(){
     // ...
   },
   mouseleave: function(){
    // ...
   }
}, '.tab:not(.active)');
```

Comment: Nice solution. But how can I execute it only when the class doesn't contain `active`?

Answer (score 9):

This blog addresses exactly what you're asking about:

http://ajpiano.com/the-opposite-of-jquerys-is-method-is-not-not-it-is-is/

The very last line of it says:

The opposite of jQuery’s `.is()` method is not `.not()`.

Comment: Yes, nice article, guess I was right on that point. But it only explains with an `if` statement..

Comment: So would I write `element!.is(:checked)` or `!element.is(:checked)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `is()` in combination with the `:not` selector.

```
if( $(this).is(':not (.active)') ){}
```

Here's jsFiddle based on the Jquery documentation for `is()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hjff5/

Comment: _"I know this can be achieved by checking it with `if( $(this).is('.active') ){}`"_

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but it is good for reference.  To check whether an element is disabled using jQuery.

IS:

```
if($(this).is('.disabled')){
    // Do something
}
```

IS NOT:

```
if(!$(this).is('.disabled')){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: D'oh, of course this is the best answer.

Comment: This isn't correct for this question.  "this" will always have one element, but jQuery collections can have multiple elements.  So if there are two elements and one .disabled and the other isn't, .is() should return true... but something like .isnot() should also return true since there is one element in the set that is not .disabled.